# How to include browserHistory using ReactRouter in non-node app?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

was experimenting with react and was replacing hashHistory with browserHostory. The application is a static application running on apache server and not on node. Have used the libraries  for React, Reaact-dom, ReactRouter and created js pages for various routes. The replaced code doesn't seem working and on console got the message `Uncaught ReferenceError: browserHistory is not defined` . Below is he code for the same ? I want to replace hash history with browserHistory.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            var destination = document.querySelector("#container");
            var { Router, Route,  IndexRoute, IndexLink, Link } = ReactRouter;

            ReactDOM.render(React.createElement(Router,{ history : browserHistory },React.createElement(
                Route,{ path: "/", component: App },
                React.createElement(IndexRoute,             { component: Home }),
                React.createElement(Route, { path: "/stuff",   component: Stuff }),
                React.createElement(Route, { path: "/contact", component: Contact }),
                React.createElement(Route, { path: "/event",   component: Event }),
                React.createElement(Route, { path: "/search",  component: Search }),
                React.createElement(Route, { path: "/fetch",   component: Fetch }),
                React.createElement(Route, { path: "/socket",  component: Socket }),
                React.createElement(Route, { path: "/form",    component: Form }) 
              )
            ), destination);

          </script>
```

If used `node.js` then could have imported the browserHistory, but here I am using `react-router` library in the html page. How to overcome this issue ?
[image: Image after discussion.]

Answer (score 0):

You need to import `browserHistory` too.

```
var { Router, Route,  IndexRoute, IndexLink, Link, browserHistory } = ReactRouter;
```

Comment: But, if I add the same, i am not getting the expected result. The page which should have contents and links to other routes is coming blank. While checking in React Dev Tools for chrome, the content in between `React` tags is coming null. Have added the image for the same.

Comment: @Worker Try this `var browserHistory = ReactRouter.browserHistory;`